# Issues with social login with vuejs and django-rest-auth

Tags: django, vue.js

I am working with APIs for the first time and was looking at how to set up social app authentication for the project. I have `django-rest-auth` set up for the backend that basically uses the django allauth framework. So when I pass an access token to the backend using the API view, it works.

Now that I have moved to vuejs for the front end, I am absolutely clueless on how to make it work with my API.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm a total beginner for vuejs and have been working on django framework for a bit more than a month. Thanks in advance!

My URL settings in VueJS:

[image: my url settings in vuejs based on a tutorial]

The error I get is:

[image: The error I get]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross origin content is blocked by same origin policy. Use https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers to allow cross origin access. If you are interested in details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS